# How to add total on cart and place order in cart with one click?

Tags: php, cart

I am having some trouble with adding up the total in a cart. I need the cart to be able to add the total of the quantity of items then add a grand total in the order then finally click a Place Order button to be able to order everything inside the cart.

Currently I am able to change the quantity but I have to select the product ID and then choose a quantity, instead of this there should be a little box near each item in the cart where I can type in the quantity.

I then need a grand total in the bottom where all items are added up and a Place Order button when clicked all items in the cart should be ordered in one go.

Currently I have to click place order for each item to place a order so I have to go back and forward, which isnt the right way of doing it.

Please help me i'm still a learner.

Thanks in advance
I will supply the code.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

 $totalAll = 0;

//Include session details
require_once('auth.php');

//Include database connection details
require_once('connection/config.php');

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//checks if id is set in the url
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    //retrive the first quantity from the quantities table
    $quantities=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quantities")
    or die("Something is wrong ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($quantities);
    $quantity_value = $row['quantity_value'];

    //get id value
    $food_id = $_GET['id'];

    //retrive food_price from food_details based on $food_id
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food_details WHERE food_id='$food_id'") or die("A problem has occured ... \n" . "Our team is working on it at the moment ... \n" . "Please check back after few hours.");
    $food_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $food_price=$food_row['food_price'];

    //get member_id from session
    $member_id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

    //define default values for quantity(got from $row), total($food_price*$quantity_value), and flag_0
    $quantity_id = $row['quantity_id'];
    $total = $food_price*$quantity_value;
    $flag_0 = 0;


    //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "INSERT INTO cart_details(member_id, food_id, quantity_id, total, flag) VALUES('$member_id','$food_id','$quantity_id','$total','$flag_0')";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        header("location: cart.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        die("A problem has occured with the system " . mysql_error());
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want but from your first sentence I would guess that you will need a loop in your code that sums up the quantity and price. In your codesample there is no such loop. Such loop would look something like this: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ /*ADD STUFF TO A VARIABLE*/ }

Comment: What I mean is for example: £2.50 then theres a option to choose quantity such as 2 which will make the total of that item £5.00, and then i need a grand total for all items in the cart

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently only gets ONE id from the url but in order to calculate the total for the whole cart you need all the ids in your cart. Usally they get saved to $_SESSION. You can view the inside of your session with this code: var_dump($_SESSION); It's also possible that the IDs are saved to the database to some kind of cart table. In your code I don't understand why you just get the first item from the quantities table. I'm pretty sure the table is somehow connected to the food table (I guess via food_id).

If you got the IDs from your session your code should look something like this (not testet because of sql statements):

```
<?php 
$member_id = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']; //get member_id from session before the loop

$food_ids = array($id1, $id2, $id3); //you need all $food_id added to cart instead of just 1 from url, usally saved to $_SESSION

$grandTotal = 0;
foreach ($food_ids as $food_id) { //LOOP THROUGH IDs
    //retrive quantity of food in cart from the quantities table
    $quantities=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quantities WHERE food_id='$food_id'") //there must be a connection between quantities and food so I added food_id="xxx"
    or die("Something is wrong ... \n" . mysql_error()); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($quantities);
    $quantity_value = $row['quantity_value'];

    //retrive food_price from food_details based on $food_id
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food_details WHERE food_id='$food_id'") 
    or die("A problem has occured ... \n" . "Our team is working on it at the moment ... \n" . "Please check back after few hours.");
    $food_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $food_price=$food_row['food_price'];


    //define default values for quantity(got from $row), total($food_price*$quantity_value), and flag_0
    $quantity_id = $row['quantity_id'];
    $total = $food_price*$quantity_value;
    $grandTotal = $grandTotal + $total; //add total of this product to the $grandTotal from last time inside this loop
    $flag_0 = 0;


    //Create INSERT query
    $qry = "INSERT INTO cart_details(member_id, food_id, quantity_id, total, flag) VALUES('$member_id','$food_id','$quantity_id','$total','$flag_0')";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        header("location: cart.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        die("A problem has occured with the system " . mysql_error());
    }
} /*Now you have $grandTotal calculated*/?>
```